# how to access one name value pair from a JSON object

Tags: c#, jquery, json

let's say i have this JSON object passed back from the server via

```
JavascriptSerializer oSer = new JavascriptSerializer();
string sJson = oSer.Serialize(myObject);
```

the json that i get returned to my client via ajax call is

```
"{\"IsValid\":false,\"EmployeeId\":null,\"fullName\":\"a\",\"EmailAddress\":\"n/a\",\"PhoneNumber\":\"n/a\"}"
```

so after `$.parseJSON(result);`

is it possible to retrieve just the IsValid value without looping through the whole object name/value pairs?

UPDATE:
seems like when the json gets to the client the : gets changed into = between the name value pairs.  so now i have to figure out how to replace the = with a : so i can parse and access it like a true object property notation.

```
success: function (data)
                    {
                        data.replace("=", ":");
                    }
```

doesn't work.

also i have the ajax dataType property set to 'json'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem.  in the

```
  $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: "myJson=" + jsonData,
            url: "/myURL",
            success: function (result)
            {
               //some code
            }
         });
```

I had dataType: 'json'
that was what was converting my correctly configured JSON from the serve

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop through each field anyway - just access it as a direct property of the result from `parseJSON`.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
alert(obj.IsValid);
```

Comment: that only works for a json string passed back from the server.  When you serialize an OBJECT via C#, you get type OBJECT OBJECT back.  the only thing i found was using $.each() to get the name/value pairs

Answer (score 1):

```
var myObj = $.parseJSON(result);
myObj.IsValid
```

Make sure that your result is surrounded by quotation marks, single quotes are Ok.

Comment: they are there in code, i just didn't paste them into the question

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
alert(obj.IsValid);
```